# Group sequential Design

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, sequential-analysis

Can anyone recommend a paper which provides a nice introduction or summary of group sequential design.

Answer (score 3):

Personally- I find [Group Sequential and Adaptive Designs - A Review of Basic Concepts and Points of Discussion](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18663761) by Marc Vandemeulebroecke a great reference.

Comment: Does this article provide a discussion on frequentist vs. bayesian approach to RCTs?

Comment: @chl: No. Frequentist only.

Answer (score 1):

Pocock "Group Sequential Methods in Clinical Trials" 1977 Biometrika is a foundational article and well worth the read.

Answer (score 0):

regulatory guidelines often provide a very useful and succinct introduction; they distill much of the thinking that originally appears in esoteric stats journals, and reduce it to the salient info. For example, see the FDA Guidance for Industry document on adaptive designs, section V part D re sequential methods.